# How can I write a ravenDB query in the studio that finds all fields that are not empty

Tags: lucene, ravendb

I'm new to lucene, day 1 new. So I've read a tutorial on lucene and spent a while trying to work out how to find a non null value in lucene.

So I have a document called Inspect
The document has two fields I'm interested in: Inspect and Direct.

```
{
    "Inspect": "Feather",
    "Direct": {} 
}
```

I want to find all documents where Inspect = "Feather" and Direct is not empty.
I am also interested in finding documents where Direct is also empty.

I am doing this in the ravenDB studio, so I am using lucene. I have tried a few things like

```
Inspect: Feather
And NOT 
Direct: [[NULL_VALUE]]
```

However this doesn't seem to work. Any advice or some direction would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run a query like this:

```
Inspect: Feather AND NOT Direct.Count: 0
```

When you are comparing to a null object, it fails, `Direct` is not null, but with the `.Count` there you are actually counting the number of properties in the object, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Amazing, it works like a charm. A side note for the future. How may I search for a specific element in an array (maybe array of objects) or A list of objects? 

So if I have something like 
"Direct": { "First": "This is first",
"second" { "one": "how may I access this object if it exists" },
"Third": "The Third" 
}

The solution does not seem easy to find. I am trying to use lucene to do the query. Whenever I search I wind up with results on how to do it with RavenDB in C#.

Comment: Can you create a new question with the full details, I'm not able to follow it in this format.

Answer (score 1):

@stacka Hi! I'm also rather new to RavenDB, but I have some ideas that may help you. First of all, use the '-' (minus) character instead of NOT. It's a convention. Second, you may face the problem that query cannot be run against db, when any property is not indexed. So, you should create one including the field you want to query against. Hope, this would help.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It is much appreciated.